# XQuery Distinct Values

Tags: html, xpath, xquery

I am trying to find the teams that Shaquille O'Neal played in from the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highest-paid_NBA_players_by_season

```
let $doc := doc("NBApaid.xml")//table
for $x in $doc/tr
where $x/td/a="Shaquille O'Neal"
for $y in $x/td/a
where $y != "Shaquille O'Neal"
return distinct-values($y)
```

The output is:

```
Cleveland Cavaliers
Phoenix Suns
Phoenix Suns
Miami Heat
Miami Heat
Miami Heat
Los Angeles Lakers
Los Angeles Lakers
Los Angeles Lakers
Los Angeles Lakers
Los Angeles Lakers
Los Angeles Lakers
```

However, I only want the distinct strings, i.e an output that looks like this:

```
Cleveland Cavaliers
Phoenix Suns
Miami Heat
Los Angeles Lakers
```

I have no idea where I'm going wrong here, been stuck for about 2 hours on this specific problem where I can't compare two values in different rows of the data, i.e when I use the  count()-function I only get a column of ones:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Yes, this is homework, but I am not asking for the whole solution; only what is wrong with my code.

Comment: You need to call `distinct-values()` higher up in your loop. It takes a sequence as input, and you're just calling it repeatedly on each individual item.

Comment: @wst Where do I call distinct-values? I don't quite understand how I would modify the code to keep it a sequence if that's the problem.

Comment: First try wrapping it around your entire expression.

Comment: @wst Haha, it worked! Thanks pal, I think I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html):

#### XPath

```
xidel -s https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highest-paid_NBA_players_by_season -e '
  distinct-values(//tr[td/a="Shaquille O'\''Neal"]/td[last()]/a)
'
Cleveland Cavaliers
Phoenix Suns
Miami Heat
Los Angeles Lakers
Orlando Magic
```

#### XQuery

```
xidel -s https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highest-paid_NBA_players_by_season --xquery '
  for $x in //tr
  where $x/td/a="Shaquille O&apos;Neal"
  group by $teams:=$x/td[last()]/a
  return $teams
'
Cleveland Cavaliers
Los Angeles Lakers
Miami Heat
Orlando Magic
Phoenix Suns
```